# Does Xcode have a region feature like in the Microsoft Visual Studio?

Tags: xcode

Does `xcode` have a region feature like in `microsoft visual studio`? If It has how can i create it?
[image: Here is the screen shot of a region feature from Microsoft Visual Studio]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code folding ribbon" option in Xcode->Preferences->Text Editing needs to be selected. the follow this picture:

[image]

Or you can directly fold the code when you click on `open parenthesis` "{" with command then you will get option to fold the code:

[image]

Comment: i can't see pictures that you have shared. Maybe because of my network. I am gonna check your reply (with pictures) tomorrow from another network. Thanks for reply.